# Create data frame from matrix elements

Tags: r

I Have a matrix 'Feats' which has 3 columns of data with feature titles:

```
Feats <- structure(list(6.25, 3.125, 21.875, NA, NA, NA, 0.0625, 2L, 1L, 
7L, 22L, NA, -2.22250786972976, 1.29105036381309, 0.291962041644914, 
-0.236742861516547, NA, NA, 206.568058210094, 26.5635498091798, 
236.313419096143, NA, -177.80062957838, 206.568058210094, 
6.6734180947409, -1.72176626557489, NA, 0.03, 0.1225, 0.37, 
NA, 0.0281666666666667, 0.0338, 0.338, 0.338, 0.124, 19, 
7.8291135544129, 6.09286912790999, 1.84893765231614, 0.567403653479842, 
NA, NA, structure(2L, .Label = c("", "Resting"), class = "factor"), 
12.5, 9.375, 25, NA, NA, NA, 0.13125, 4L, 3L, 8L, 17L, NA, 
-4.61233109314598, 2.80969059774635, 0.310781140139641, 2.01618235362392, 
NA, NA, 247.38710328687, 30.960434438506, 270.000001621512, 
NA, -184.493243725839, 149.850165213139, 6.21562280279281, 
18.9758339164604, NA, 0.06, 0.16390625, 0.34, NA, 0.0316923076923077, 
0.0312857142857143, 0.412, 0.438, 0.062, 24, 10.757380314083, 
4.99655985128538, 1.32689481272002, 0.497119334728677, NA, 
NA, structure(2L, .Label = c("", "Resting"), class = "factor"), 
28.125, 12.5, 18.75, NA, NA, NA, 0.1375, 9L, 4L, 6L, 13L, 
NA, -8.28559386168768, 4.93024930500612, 0.000801170003772261, 
3.3100091226664, NA, NA, 285.259587496729, 26.5665579000233, 
246.377341685035, NA, -147.299446430003, 197.209972200245, 
0.021364533433927, 40.7385738174326, NA, 0.06, 0.248125, 
0.62, NA, 0.0587272727272727, 0.033375, 0.646, 0.534, 0.124, 
18, 13.5914203301306, 4.06478678366543, 1.41204036306107, 
0.497119356632411, NA, NA, structure(2L, .Label = c("", "Resting"
), class = "factor")), .Dim = c(44L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(
c("movPercentLeft", "movPercentRight", "movPercentForward", 
"movPercentUTurn", "movPercentNonMov", "changeRateMovNonMov", 
"changeRateBetweenAnyMov", "headingAccumLeft", "headingAccumRight", 
"accumForward", "accumNonMoving", "accumUTurn", "rateOfChangeLeft", 
"rateOfChangeRight", "rateOfChangeForward", "rateOfChangeNonMoving", 
"rateOfChangeUTurn", "maxHeadingChangeLeft", "maxHeadingChangeRight", 
"maxHeadingChangeForward", "maxHeadingChangeNonMoving", "maxHeadingChangeUTurn", 
"meanHeadingChangePerLeft", "meanHeadingChangePerRight", 
"meanHeadingChangePerForward", "meanHeadingChangePerNonMoving", 
"meanHeadingChangePerUTurn", "minSpeed", "meanSpeed", "maxSpeed", 
"minAccel", "meanAccelPos", "meanAccelNeg", "accumAccelPos", 
"accumAccelNeg", "maxAccel", "changesPosNeg", "accumDistanceMov", 
"accumDistanceNonMov", "maxDistanceMov", "maxDistanceNonMov", 
"accumTimeMov", "accumTimeNonMov", "Class"), c("1", "2", 
"3")))
```

I would like to create a single data frame 'Features' such that:

```
Features <- data.frame(Feats[ ,1], Feats [ ,2], Feats[ ,3])
```

This example has 3 feats columns but 'Features' could have many eventually. I am thinking something along the lines of a for loop to achieve this but is there something more elegant?

Comment: Is `data.frame(Feats)` not what you want?

Comment: No, I will need to save it as an arff file eventually so I need it so that each feature has its respective value.

Comment: I don't know what's going on here but the answer is likely `Features <- do.call(data.frame,Feats)`

Comment: Simple as that it seems! Thanks for that. How could I modify it so that the features are still visible i.e. 'movPercentLeft' and not 'X1.' ?

Comment: `data.frame(t(Feats))`? That way your columns are variables and rows are observations, i.e. it's tidy data.

Comment: Yes, what I was looking for however was variable followed by value repeated for all three data columns e.g. movPercentLeft (21) movPercentRight (22).....Resting. movPercentLeft (19), movPercentRight (23) ....Resting etc. Exactly how my 'Features' object creates it.